# iOS - EXC bad access, previously worked on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

Unless I'm out of my mind, this was working properly on iOS4. I updated to iOS5, and now it's throwing this bad access error on `[indexPath section]`. It's on a `UITableView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    // Get the cell label and value
    NSLog(@"section: %@", [indexPath section]); /* BAD ACCESS ERROR HERE */
...
```

Comment: Just to note, for your reassurance, that I have had a number of things (quite different to this) that worked fine in iOS4 that were causing issues or outright crashes in iOS 5... so your experience is not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log statement itself is causing the error.

```
NSLog(@"section: %@", [indexPath section]); /* BAD ACCESS ERROR HERE */
```

You are trying to log an integer as if it was an object. It should be:

```
NSLog(@"section: %i", [indexPath section]);
```

Comment: Good call, thanks! I'm still having a problem with it though, I'm going to open up a new question.